# How to compare two objects in a Pair and return the max one

Tags: android, kotlin, oop, math

I have an object of type `Pair<Object1, Object2>`, now I'm trying to return the object in which the comparison of its values is lower.

I see in kotlin that we have the followin function

```
/**
 * Returns the smaller of two values.
 * 
 * If values are equal, returns the first one.
 */
@SinceKotlin("1.1")
public actual fun <T : Comparable<T>> minOf(a: T, b: T): T {
    return if (a <= b) a else b
}
```

This one should work for me, since I need to see which of the two objects has its minimum value and return that object

so I'm expecting to return the object as

```
minOf(pair.first.price, pair.second.price).storeName
```

But this one yields into the Double comparator

How can I add the comparator for these two objects and return the object that has the min value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question lacks some details about your data structure and what does it mean the object is lower. However, if I understand your example correctly, this is how you can do this:

```kotlin
minOf(pair.first, pair.second, compareBy { it.price }).storeName
```

Alternatively, we can do it more concisely by converting to a list, although I think this could be misleading and it is not worth the performance hit:

```kotlin
pair.toList().minBy { it.price }.storeName
```

Comment: the context is a crypto app that I need to know from more than 10.000 results the max of a certain pair between two exchanges, since this is a combination of all posible exchanges, is easier to have the logic this way than with the if statment, also is easier to understand at first view

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
if (pair.first.price <= pair.second.price) pair.first else pair.second
```

Comment: yes, already did this, but I'm looking to use the above function, is there a way ?

Comment: @SNM: Not directly. You could implement `Comparable` on whatever class this is and have it use `price` for its comparison. Then, you would use `minOf(pair.first, pair.second)`. Or, use the `minOf()` that has the signature `fun <T> minOf(a: T, b: T, comparator: Comparator<in T>): T` and supply a `Comparator` lambda expression. I think that will be more verbose than what I have.

Comment: yes, exactly, thanks a lot for the answer byw @CommonsWare , and thanks for you time, I was looking for something provided in the accepted answer